# IOS: timeago date functionality for future

Tags: ios, nsdate, future

I would like to implement functionality similar to Kevin Lawler's [timeago](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo) library (now part of Mathew York's datetools) but for the future. Datetools does not appear to cover the future.

In particular I'd like to do the following:

if the day is today

'Today at 3.'

If the day is later this week, 
'Wednesday at 4'

If the date is next week.

Next Wednesday

If the date is next month

Next month.

If the date is next June.

'Next June';

if the date is in 5 years.

In 2021

Does anyone know if such a library exists?

I have tried writing my own using doesRelativeDateFormatting along the following lines but am stuck on how to modify the output.

```
NSDate *date = self.event.date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];

dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Future functionality in a timeago format is available in other languages/frameworks but can't figure out how to do it in IOS.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried FormatterKit? https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit

Comment: That looks like an interesting library but like it only handles dates in the past

Comment: Have you checked the samples? In Sample there is an option for future date also.